# NSRegularExpression gives incorrect matches for pattern

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, nsregularexpression

`Goal` : Multiple splits of the string, Each must have `50` characters. It would be really great if I can do it by proper word wrapping. It is okay to have the last split as less than `50` characters.

I am using this method to split a `String` into multiple parts. I have used a regular expression for this, which is given below.

```
                           "\\G\\s*(.{1,50})(?=\\s|$)"
```

And used this `NSURLRegularExpression` to find the corresponding splits.

```
extension String {

   func getSplits()
   {
     let pattern = try? NSRegularExpression(pattern: "\\G\\s*(.{1,50})(?=\\s|$)", options: NSRegularExpressionOptions.DotMatchesLineSeparators)

        if let matches = pattern?.matchesInString(self, options: NSMatchingOptions.ReportCompletion , range: NSMakeRange(0, self.characters.count)) as [NSTextCheckingResult]?
        {
            for (index, result) in matches.enumerate()
            {
                // Statements
            }
        }
    }
}
```

But the problem is that, whenever I put `English` text it returns me the proper splits. But whenever I put text other than `English`, it seems to be showing incorrect splits. As in each split must have 50 characters right? But number of characters in the output are sometimes `5` or `10` or `some random number`. Randomly splitting, I have a doubt? Is there anything to do with the `\n` character or `\r`? No right?

I have tried all option types of `NSRegularExpressionOptions` and `NSMatchingOptions`. Even no options, but same thing happened.

If you are testing, this string will help you, test it with this `Malayalam Language` text ->

```
കുളച്ചല്‍ തുറമുഖം നിര്‍മ്മിക്കാനുള്ള നീക്കം യുക്തിരഹിത പദ്ധതിയെന്നാണ് മുഖ്യമന്ത്രി പിണറായി വിജയന്‍ മറുപടി നല്‍കിയത്. പ്രധാനമന്ത്രിയെ നേരില്‍ കണ്ട് ഇക്...
പൊതുജനങ്ങളുടെ നികുതിപ്പണം യുക്തിരഹിതമായി ഉപയോഗിക്കുന്നതിനുള്ള തെളിവാണ് കുളച്ചല്‍. 1000 ദിവസം കൊണ്ട് മുന്‍നിശ്ചയപ്രകാരം പദ്ധതി പൂര്‍ത്തിയാക്കും. തുറമുഖ...
```

Do you have any thoughts on this?

Comment: How many graphemes vs. characters?

Comment: @Feldur As in? I didn't understand.

Comment: The grapheme's are the number of characters that you would see in the characters view. The characters could be a significantly larger number as they will need to combine to form the complete grapheme. There are as well, multiple ways the characters combine to give you a given grapheme